# Updating multiple columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to update several columns in a big table with household survey data. About 20 columns have expenditures reported as negative values. However, I want to have the absolute values (for producing a latex table). 
I only manage to produce a new data.table with only these updated columns.  Here is an example. I only want to have to update the columns 2 and 3:

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4),c(-2,-3,-4,-5),c(-1,-4,-5,-6),c(1,2,3,6))
test[,lapply(.SD,abs),.SDcols=2:3]
```

This gives me a data.table with the columns 2 and 3 and not the full data.table.

I can easily do this making data.frames and using cbind:

```
df1.test<-data.frame(test)[,-c(2:3)]
df2.test<-data.frame(test[,lapply(.SD,abs),.SDcols=2:3])
test<-data.table(cbind(df1.test,df2.test))
```

but perhaps there is a smarter way in data.table.

Thanks
Renger

Comment: You can use the dplyr package `library(dplyr); test  <- test %>% mutate(V2 = abs(V2), V3=abs(V3))`

Comment: Are you familiar with the `:=` operator?

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
test[,2:3 := lapply(.SD,abs),.SDcols=2:3][]
```

Or a faster approach would be to use `set` (as suggested by @Frank) as it provides direct assignment by reference with low overhead

```
for(j in 2:3){
  set(test, i=NULL, j=j, value=abs(test[[j]]))
}
```